# Why assertEquals(a, b) instead of assert(a == b)?

Tags: unit-testing

Why most (all?) unit test frameworks have large APIs with separate functions for specifying different types of boolean conditions (eg. `assertEquals`, `assertNotEqual`, etc) instead of using single `assert` function (or language construct) with desired boolean expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple `assert` will only throw `AssertionError` stating that the asserted conditation evaluated to false:

```
assert "foo".equals("boo")

java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
```

(not to mention `assert string1 == string2` is incorrect due to reference comparison)

By passing both `a` and `b` the library can include them in the error message. Here: [FEST assertions](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x/wiki):

```
assertThat("foo").isEqualTo("boo");

//throws:
Exception in thread "main" org.junit.ComparisonFailure:
expected:<'[b]oo'> but was:<'[f]oo'>
```

Note that some languages are more powerful:

In Groovy (example from: [Groovy 1.7 Power Assert](http://dontmindthelanguage.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/groovy-1-7-power-assert/)):

```
a = 10
b = 9

assert 91 == a * b
```

yields:

```
Assertion failed: 

assert 91 == a * b
          |  | | |
          |  10| 9
          |    90
          false

    at ConsoleScript2.run(ConsoleScript2:4)
```

In Scala ([ScalaTest](http://scalatest.org/getting_started_with_fun_suite)) there is a special `===` operator:

```
assert(1 === 2)
```

yields `1 did not equal 2`.

Comment: OK, now I see -- it's technically hard to retrieve the original expression at runtime. (But I it should be possible, at least in Java -- testing framework has access to the source code and error provides the location)

Comment: @Aivar: Nope, the test framework does **not** have access to the source code, moreover some variable names might not be accessible. It is however possible in Groovy with some compiler support and in ScalaTest using special `===` operator. See my updates.

Comment: The Groovy version looks best to me. Hopefully other languages gain similar testing facilities in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two reasons:

1. It's more declarative
2. It allows the library to automatically provide more detailed assertion failed messages.

Declarative means saying **what** you want it to do, not **how** you want it done.

The difference is slight when talking about something as well-supported as object equality, but consider comparing two collections. You could have `assertIsSubsetOf`, `assertAreSameIncludingOrder`, `assertAreSameButOrderIsIrrelevant` - I'd much rather read those english names than the long, involved, and easily messed-up implementations of them.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with point 1. Point 2 makes sense, if one prefers messages like `Your variable a should be equal to variable b, but turns out they're not` instead of `assertion a==b failed` (sorry for exaggeration).

Comment: OK, I forgot that it's not always easy to get even `assertion a==b failed` at runtime

Comment: about `assertIsSubsetOf(...)` -- I'd prefer `assert(isSubsetOf(...))` because I would need subset condition also in other contexts besides unit-testing, so why duplicate?

Comment: The writers of these test libraries could indeed decompose their code to provide general purpose methods like that. Except they're not in the business of general purpose code, they write testing tools, which is generally not included in production code. It is hardly duplication, but they are, after all, just convenience methods. If you don't like them, you don't have to use them.

Comment: Also, in that case, you lose the detailed exception messages, which is a major convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I used to question this, until I realised. If you put the two values into the API, then the function can report the 'values' that don't assert. Rather than the fact that they don't match you get

> blah blah blah **99 doesn't equal 10003** blah blah blah

Which in gives you clues in the test results to the issue that are wrong. Any help that computer can give is welcome and is completely in the ethos of extreme testing.

Comment: Right, I forgot about the values